# Jquery DataTables (table/grid) server-side processing in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and Jquery DataTable to display records. I need exactly MVC example like this link have.

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? what is the requirement exactly?

Comment: I want to load records in HTML table & want to apply jquery datatables. I have tried all records loading at client side, but it is not good when we have large amount of records.

Comment: What I suggest you is better load a data using json/xml/html from server to datatable by setting the server url

Comment: please provide the code you already tried or a FIDDLE that points to a specific issue.  what you are asking is very broad.

Comment: I tried, I have more than 1 lacs records to show. When records are populated by Jquery datatable's js, my browser screen goes in not responding mode, after some time it will load all data.

Comment: @erikrunia, I dont have FIDDLE yet, I have updated my question you can see hyperlink, please see it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool , library or favorite off-site resource or ask for raw code are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @ArunChandranC, Before posting this question I searched on net. I dont find any link or example for .NET.

Comment: using datatables will not solve your issue of loading all records at client side.  everything will still be loaded in the client, just hidden and shown small chunks at a time. you need to implement some sort of paging/sorting mechanism on your backend.

Comment: @erikrunia, I know this, it will be loaded at client side. I asked how to get small chunks of data (only requested rows) from database (server side) and how to apply (i.e. searching, sorting & pagination).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for you.

Your view code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/Employee/List/"
    } );
} );
```

In Employee Controller return a `JSON formatted employee list`

```
public ActionResult List()
{

   List<Employee> empList=//load from repository;  
   return Json(empList);

}
```

Comment: At this line of code, List<Employee> empList=//load from repository;  Do I have to load all records if I want to do?

Comment: How it will handle processing while searching through search box?

Comment: @Chints, Yes. It depends on how you designed. You need to get the list of records from database

Comment: @Chints, It will again hit the same action method. Please check the request parameters value like sorting info, search text and filter the list and send the result back from action method.

Comment: I will try this. See you later after implementing this one.